# Can I add two proptypes together after they are rendered? If so, how can I accomplish that?

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, react-proptypes

()I have a div with a prop that I would like to display based on whether a prop is bigger in number than another prop. I have a lot going on in this particular component and I'm concerned that all of the following things I'm trying to do are not possible.

this.props.currentValue < this.props.newValue is not working for me, but everything else is working just fine.

I'm very new to React. Any help would be awesome!

Oh, and the value of currentValue and newValue are inside of the rates component on a separate page.

```
import React, {PropTypes, Component} from 'react';
import Header from '../compare-table-header/compare-table-header';
import './compare-table-row.css';

export class Rates extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.displayThing = this.displayThing.bind(this);
}

displayThing() {
    const increase = <div>{this.props.details}</div>;
    const thing = <div>hi</div>;
    if (this.props.currentValue < this.props.newValue) {
        return increase;
    } else {
        return thing;
    }
}

render() {
    const {currentValue, newValue} = this.props;

    return (
        <div>
            <Header heading="Rates" />
                    <div className="value-heading">{currentValue}</div>
                    <div className="value-heading">{newValue}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div>{this.displayThing()}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}

Rates.propTypes = {
    currentValue: PropTypes.number,
    newValue: PropTypes.number
};
```

Comment: "this.props.currentValue < this.props.newValue is not working for me." What do you mean? Is it not displaying anything?

Comment: That fixed it thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line with `this.displayThing` isn't rendering anything because you're passing a reference to the function itself, instead of calling the function and rendering the value it returns.

That line should do what you expect if you change `this.displayThing` to `this.displayThing()`.

But you also have some mismatched tags. The Header component is opened and closed on the same line. From your indentation, it looks like you meant for the lines below it to be rendered as children of the Header component, but that's not what's actually happening.

You could clean that up like this:

```
return (
    <div>
        <Header heading="Rates">
            <div className="value-heading">{currentValue}</div>
            <div className="value-heading">{newValue}</div>                        
        </Header>

        <div>{this.displayThing()}</div>
    </div>
);
```

Or, if your Header component doesn't render any children, that might look like this:

```
return (
    <div>
        <Header heading="Rates" />

        <div className="value-heading">{currentValue}</div>
        <div className="value-heading">{newValue}</div>                        

        <div>{this.displayThing()}</div>
    </div>
);
```

---

If you want to go a little further, you can also remove some code and simplify the class a little by defining the `displayThing` function as an arrow function:

Instead of this:

```
export class Rates extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.displayThing = this.displayThing.bind(this);
    }

    displayThing() {
        const increase = <div>{this.props.details}</div>;
        const thing = <div>hi</div>;
        if (this.props.currentValue < this.props.newValue) {
            return increase;
        } else {
            return thing;
        }
    }

    // ... rest of the class
}
```

you can make `displayThing` into an arrow function and get rid of the constructor, like this:

```
export class Rates extends Component {
    displayThing = () => {
        const increase = <div>{this.props.details}</div>;
        const thing = <div>hi</div>;
        if (this.props.currentValue < this.props.newValue) {
            return increase;
        } else {
            return thing;
        }
    }

    // ... rest of the class
}
```

The class works the same either way, but it saves a few lines of code.

Comment: I had to cut down the code a bit and missed some things, but you were correct. Adding the () to the displayThings function fixed it thank you!